# Access Database Normalization

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, database-design, normalization

I'm currently working on trying to normalize an existing database. My problem is similar to the issue in this video http://youtu.be/4q-keGvUnag?t=5m1s at around 5 minutes in.

What he says not to do (having two columns for books that have two authors) is the problem my database has. I was wondering if it would be possible for a query to modify the table to only have one author column and separate rows for each author.

so:

(1)    [book title]    [isbn]    [author#1]    [author#2]

should be like:

(1)    [book title]    [isbn]    [author#1]

(2)    [book title]    [isbn]    [author#2]

Comment: Is having two rows for the same book really that much better of a solution?  Seems like maybe author should be its own table here.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that since the relationship is M:N, there should be an intersection table for the book-author relationship:

Books table

```
bookId (PK)   | bookTitle     | isbn | etc...
```

Authors table

```
authorId (PK) | authorName    | etc...
```

Intersection table

```
bookId (PK)   | authorId (PK) | etc...
```

This is the most correct way to do this, database-wise.

If you have no interest in authors as an entity, you can skip the `authors` table and replace `authorId` with `authorName` in the `intersection` table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you described here is normalization. In normalized database you would have

```
Table1 -  bookId, title, isbn, authorId
Table2 -  authorId, Name...
Table3 -  book_authorId, bookId, authorId <-- assign authors to book
```

But for your specific question, the way you describe, here what you can do. First, create second record:

```
Insert into <table> (title, isbn, author#1) 
     Select title, isbn, author#2 from <table> where not author#2 is null
```

It is described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Now, you can remove the column `author#2`

These actions should create what you described in your question

Comment: Whoever downvoted did rightfully so, because I indeed didn't type the many-to-many assignment table. Now it is fixed